# How to automatically invoke a script before a git add?

Tags: git, hook, gitattributes

Here's my use case: I commit PNGs and other stuff in my Git repo. I would like to apply a specific process to every PNGs I would like to commit and this is the result of the process I finally want to commit (the potential modified PNG).

At the beginning I thought about a hook (like a `pre-commit`) but it's a little weird because the process will change the file so I will need to re-add it! And according to what I [read](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html), there is no `pre-add` hook (or something like that).

May be a solution is to create a git alias ? But I don't want to change - too much -  the way people work, I'm searching for a smooth and transparent way.

If you have a clue... even if the clue is to change my process idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may want to consider a smudge & clean filter, with the `clean` being applied during the git add, and the smudge during checkout. These can be allocated by file type. Look at the 'git attributes(5)' man page and [Git SCM book : Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).

Comment: Hi @philip-oakley
thanks for the reply, your solution seems to be the right one: The "clean" filter is run when files are staged.

I will try to use it and tell you if it's ok!

Comment: the solution is ok but it's nice to rewrite file but a little complicated to process an image :) I need to investigate more

Comment: Since the page is quite long, it would be useful to summarize the method here (I have tries to use it, to no avail).

Comment: So... how exactly does this answer the question?

Comment: @SephReed The response indicates that you can set Git (attributes) up such that on every checkout it runs a 'script' or filter to convert the internal file to something more readable (or whatever). It is done by file type.

Comment: Ah.  So you could have something that says "every `.zip` shall be exploded"?

Comment: @SephReed It probably gets complicated for exploding `.zip`s because they may not re-combine the same way (a known issue with zips), but if, say, it is just to get an index/dir listing of the zip contents then that's not hard. Also if it's exploded, you'd need to know what else has to go back in when you have focus on a single file. Plus zips don't compact multiple similar files that well (so I'm told).

Comment: Maybe zip was a bad example.  Compression just came to mind for this.  Less specifically, you could have a file that transforms back and forth?

Comment: @SephReed "file that transforms back and forth?" Absolutely. That's the whole purpose of the smudge/clean filter pair. https://www.juandebravo.com/2017/12/02/git-filter-smudge-and-clean/ gives one example usage.

Answer (score 9):

There may be a good reason to use `clean` instead, but there's actually nothing preventing you from re-adding the files during the `pre-commit` hook, which is a bit more intuitive in my opinion.

Your `pre-commit` would look something like:

`*run your PNG processing here*
(after processing completes) git add *.png`

The commit will then continue as usual. If you want to get fancy you can throw an `exit 1` in there when something goes wrong with the compression, and it will stop the commit.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work as intended: the pre-processing is done, but it is as if it were to late for `git add` to register any change (thus, changes seem to be frozen before this script). I tested this with a script that *generates* the added file, and that a commit done after the file was deleted: the commit message indicates that it was deleted (despite having been generated again and git "added").

Comment: It sounds like you've forgotten to take the processing time into account. I suppose I should have mentioned it in the original, but you'll need a way to tell when your processing is done and don't `git add` until then. You obviously won't register any changes if `git add` hits before the changes are even made.

Comment: `git add` is only run after the preprocessing. Now, the preprocessing processes a .ipynb file but creates a .py file (which is versioned), without using stdin as normally required by git, so maybe that's why git doesn't see that the file has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to disso, using `gulp` and `gulp-git`.

```
var git = require('gulp-git')

// ... other tasks

gulp.task('add', function(){
  return gulp.src('cdn/**')
    .pipe(git.add())
})
```

This add task is then called at the end of everything else. Then I have `gulp` set up with a pre-commit hook. Works like a charm.

So in your case, the full file might look something like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')()
var runSequence = require('run-sequence')

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return runSequence(
    'images',
    'add'
    )
})

gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
    .pipe($.cache($.imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      interlaced: true
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
})

gulp.task('add', function(){
  return gulp.src('dist/**')
    .pipe($.git.add())
})
```

(Note that I haven't tested it... I got the images task code from Google.)