# Why is there no pre-add git hook?

Tags: git

Having a pre-add hook would be useful.

I'm trying to run `clang-format` as a pre-commit hook, but everything gets complicated when there're unstaged changes. This would not be an issue if I could stash ONLY unstaged changes, but alas `git stash --keep-index` does not do that.

Comment: Unless something else is running `git add` *for* you, you can retrain yourself to run `git xyz` where `xyz` is your own alias that runs clang-format first, then runs `git add`. (Not really an answer, since it doesn't help you retrain your fingers, nor eliminate the need to do that. :-) )

Comment: Can't you run clang-format in some sort of "watch" mode, or as a plugin of your IDE, so it formats files after you save them? Also, how does having unstaged changes "complicate" things?

Comment: @CodeCaster *I* can configure vim to format on save, *I* can remember to run clang-format in watch mode (90% of the time), *I* can even code in accordance to the style guide by myself (ok this one was a blatant lie). But what I can't do is write a frictionless script to help my friends do that. I *can* sit them down and help them configure their editors (I've actually already done this :P). But the cleanest solution in my mind is a pre-add hook.

Comment: Also, your question as stated ("Why not?") is considered off-topic by some, because the answer will be _"Because"_. Could you rephrase it to ask _"How to run a command before adding files to the staging area"_ or something like that?

Comment: @CodeCaster And yeah! Great question. There are 3 versions of a file when you've staged changes. The previous commit (I'll call this `f_repo`), the staged file (I'll call this `f_staged`), and the workspace version of the file (I'll call this `f_work`). I cannot get the changes between `f_work` and `f_staged` s.t. the diff only shows the changed files. I cannot stash the changes in `f_work` to revert it back to `f_staged` cleanly (stash saves a diff between `f_repo` and `f_staged`, causing merge conflicts after formatting then stash popping)

Comment: @CodeCaster Fortunately there's already an answer to that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877877/how-to-automatically-invoke-a-script-before-a-git-add - if this question is bad and deserves to get closed then it deserves to get closed. If it gets closed, then I suppose I'll have my answer "there's no reason - it just doesn't exist."

Comment: Note: `git stash` actually saves *copies* but the copies are converted to diffs by `git stash apply` so the end effect is the same. I think your best bet is to help others configure their editors to auto-format - that's roughly the same amount of work as helping them install a hook, after all. The clean filter trick is also an option (especially since clang-format can run in a streaming mode) but then there's this weird difference between staged and work-tree copies that you will spend hours explaining.

Comment: @torek Asking for my best bet is lazy :P I can make that decision by myself. (Not that you guys don't have good opinions that I'm thankful for - it's just that if I saw a question asking "how can I enforce style for my team at work" I would not think it belonged on stack overflow). Also, there are clear benefit of making it a git hook rather than a per-editor configuration. With a `.git_template` folder, every time someone clones they'll have it. The fact that its editor agnostic is appealing to me. I'm being blocked due to my own ignorance, not due to technological limitations.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason. That's just the way it is.

If you want to make git support pre-add hooks, then you can use `filter`s. In case it's not obvious from the documentation, here's what you'd have to do:

In a gitattributes file, you assign a filter for the paths you want to hit. For example, in `.git/info/attributes` you put:

```
*.c filter=myFilter
```

Then, in one of git's config files, you'll have to define the filter.myFilter.clean command. For example, in `.git/config`:

```
[filter "myFilter"]
    clean = $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/hooks/pre-add
```

Now, every time you add a `.c` file, you will run the commands in `pre-add`.

---

(Remember to `chmod +x` your script if you want it to run, and that it's being invoked from a different script, so stdout won't be tied to your terminal unless you do something like `echo "Hi, this is a pre-add hook" > /dev/tty`)

Comment: This is a cool answer. Is there any way we can inject this on npm install in some way so that the DX for every dev is the same?

Comment: What are you npm installing? Are you npm installing git? Git configuration is definitionally not versioned. But you could have IT set up your employee machines with a configured and prepopulated [git template dir](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-inittemplateDir) to make every new repo they clone or create have this config.