# git ignore specific changes in file but not all the file

Tags: git

how to ignore some changes in a file but not all the file

example:
I want git to ignore the changes in a file if the only changes are like

```
Generation Time: 2022-02-21 16:42:18
```

if it's the only difference, I want git to skip it as changed

Comment: You can use `git add --patch` and choose the changes that you want to commit.

Comment: @DMalan I tried to apply it to all files but not working. tried to use regex `git add --patch "Generation Time: 20*" .`
any idea

Comment: Try git smudge/clean filters. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18881044/6330106

Comment: Just run `git add --patch` by itself (without the extra bit you added). Git will then ask you whether you want to add a specific change or not and you can type in `y` to add it or `n` to skip it.